# Couldn't find VkNonDispatchableHandle

Tags: c++, c++14, vulkan, validation-layers

I'm using Vulkan to create a simple program. After I resize the window, the validation layer gives me this output. The resize itself works fine. What does it say? The complete error is following:

> UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info(ERROR / SPEC): msgNum: 1567320034 - Validation Error: [ UNASSIGNED-Threading-Info ] Object 0: handle = 0xee3a9100000000b4, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_UNKNOWN; | MessageID = 0x5d6b67e2 | Couldn't find VkNonDispatchableHandle Object 0xee3a9100000000b4. This should not happen and may indicate a bug in the application.
> Objects: 1
> [0] 0xee3a9100000000b4, type: 0, name: NULL

What causes the problem?

Comment: What layer version? Which other layers are running (including implicit ones)?

Comment: Vulkan version 1.2.170.0 and this is the only layer, that is running.

Comment: VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation is the name of the layer.

Comment: The message means the threading layer is not aware that object (`0xee3a9100000000b4`) exists (i.e. it was not ever created, or was since destroyed). Object Lifetime layer should generally catch errors of this type though (so that's why it says it shouldn't usually happen). To get to bottom of this, would need debugging details...

Comment: `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump` should suffice here. Put it **before**
`VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` and it should show what the layers see.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it up.

The reason, that caused the Problem was, that I tried to destroy a Swapchain which was set to VK_NULL_HANDLE.

Comment: Destroying a null handle is legal though. Might wanna report the bug...